# Reading certain lines only from input?

Tags: java, input

If i have some code such as `input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));`                                                                        And the input file contain pairs of lines, how can I make it so only the first line from each line is imported? So in other words, every odd numbered line only?
Thanks

Comment: Read all lines and ignore the even ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to consider the use of `java.io.LineNumberReader` to make the filtering of odd lines (`lineNo % 2 == 1`) simpler. Or in an alternative approach, if you are using JDK7, you could use the `java.nio.files.Files.readAllLines()` method and again filter the odd ones upon iteration.

Comment: If i used that, and then did something like, `String line = input.readLine();` `while (lineNo % 2 != 1) `Do something` would this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = input.readLine();
while (line != null) {
   // do something with the line

   // Skip every other line
   input.readLine();
   // Get next line
   line = input.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this will read in the file and give you every 2nd line in a string buffer.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
String line;
StringBuffer endResult = new StringBuffer(1000);
int lineNumber=1;
while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
    //every odd line will be added, 1, 3, 5 etc
    if (lineNumber++%2==1) {
       endResult.append(line+"\n");
    }
}
```