# Skip every odd line using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading certain lines only from input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259905/reading-certain-lines-only-from-input)

Is there a way I can skip every odd line from a file if I am using BufferedReader?

Answer (score 1):

Just read a line and discard it:

```
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("someFileName.txt"));
String line = null;

while(true)
{
   //skip the odd line
   bReader.readLine();

   //read an even line
   line = bReader.readLine();

   if(line != null)
      //do stuff with even line
   else
      break; //end of input
}
```

Comment: you need to check for end of file ie line == null on both readlines

Comment: The first `readLine()` doesn't store anything in line

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = ...;
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = br.readLine();
    //do whatever with the data
    if (line == null) break;
}
```